# Notification method IOS xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, notifications

I have a notification set up to fire on the fire date/time from a date picker.  I would like to run a method when this happens, is there a way to do this at the time of the notification?

Here is my code

```
-(void)scheduleLocalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate{

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

    notification.fireDate = fireDate;
    notification.alertBody = @"time hit";
    notification.soundName = @"alarmSoundFile.mp3";


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first you should to set some info to identify this group of notifications (in case you will use another local notifications in future). also, for example, you can set a time interval since 1970 to fire date as ID:

```
notification.userInfo = @{@"group" : @"time hit",
                          @"id" : @(fireDate.timeIntervalSince1970)};
```

then receive notifications in appDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotification) {
        [self application:application didReceiveLocalNotification:localNotification];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    if ([(NSString *)userInfo[@"group"] isEqualToString:@"time hit"]) {
        // some actions here
    }
}
```

note: as far as i know, you can receive notification only if application will foreground at fire date OR if you will launch/enter foreground with fired notification